# elasticsearch nest query and aggs at same time

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

With Nest 5, I am trying to make a query request and to make aggregations on result:

In elasticsearch it would be this type of request:

```
POST /index/mappingname/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
        "street": "wellington"
      }
   },
    "aggs" : {
        "agg_name" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "country"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "size" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var response = Client.Search<my_class>(s => s
    .Query(p => p
        .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.street)
            .Query("wellington")
        )
    )
    .Size(1000)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms(codeBucket, t => t
            .Field("country")
            .Size(100)
        )
    )
);
```